# Using a file as lock to not run a script(or related scripts) multiple times at the same time fails when a process pool is used

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use a locking mechanism to not start two scripts(can be the same script or another connected script) at the same time. I'm using a file as a locker.

```
class LockFile:

    def __init__(self, lock_path):
        self.lock_path = lock_path

    def lock(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.lock_path):
            raise ImporterLockError
        else:
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self.lock_path), exist_ok=True)
            with open(self.lock_path, "w") as f:
                f.write.... # some info about the script

    def unlock(self):
        with contextlib.suppress(FileNotFoundError):
            os.remove(self.lock_path)
```

I'm using the lock inside a function `run_wrapper` that it will be used as a wrapper for other functions:

```
def run_wrapper(fn_to_run):
    .......
    lock = LockFile(lock_path=lock_path")
     ................

    try:
        lock.lock()
    except ImporterLockError:
        return 1
    else:
        log.debug("Importer lock acquired.")
        try:
            fn_to_run()
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            log.info("Terminated by user request.")
            return 1
        except ImporterLockError:
            return 1
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unexpected error: ....")
            return 1
        finally:
            # do some cleaning
            lock.unlock()
            print("Importer lock released.")
```

the `run wrapper` I'm using it to run a function `run` that is using multiprocessing pool.

```
run_wrapper(run)
```

```
def run():
...................
processes = set()
with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
  processes.add(pool.apply_async(task_1))
  processes.add(pool.apply_async(task_2))
  [p.get() for p in processes]
```

The issue is that when an exception is triggered in a child process, the lock mechanism is not working, the `finally: ...` in `try - except` is not executing and the `lock.unlock` is not executed
so the lock file is not deleted, even if the script exit.
So running again a script will not work because the lock file wasn't deleted and no clean operations were done.

Comment: your `lock()` method does not appear to be safe to me. Is there a reason `threading.Lock()` would not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect opportunity for a context manager.

```
class LockFile:

    def __init__(self, lock_path):
        self.lock_path = lock_path

    def lock(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.lock_path):
            raise ImporterLockError
        else:
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self.lock_path), exist_ok=True)
            with open(self.lock_path, "w") as f:
                f.write.... # some info about the script

    def unlock(self):
        with contextlib.suppress(FileNotFoundError):
            os.remove(self.lock_path)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.lock()

    def __exit__(self, __exc_type, __exc_value, __exc_traceback):
        self.unlock()
```

You can then use your `LockFile` like this:

```
with LockFile(lock_path):
    ...
    # Do whatever you need to do
```

Context managers are used to ensure that resources (such as lock files) are freed up when they are no-longer needed. By using one, we guarantee that the lock file is always cleaned up at the end of the with statement, regardless of any errors that may have happened.

Note that there is one way that this won't happen. If your program is forcefully killed with a `SIGKILL` signal (not just politely asked to exit with `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`), it won't do this clean-up, since there is no way to handle a kill signal.

Comment: How is changing the LockFile to a context manager solve the issue that child processes exception are not catch and cleaning process executed ?

Comment: @user3541631 using a context manager means that the file will be removed, even if an exception happened.